# Mysql table locking issue

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my php page

```
LOCK TABLE invoice_numbers WRITE
/*some stuff */ 
SELECT * FROM link_master
/*some stuff */ 
UNLOCK TABLES
```

My problem is that after locking the table invoice_numbers . I can't access **link_master** table, but after unlocking i can access **link_master** table

Why is it so? How can i access link_master after locking **invoice_numbers** table?

**EDIT :**

I want to lock only single table invoice_numbers. During the locking period I want to use all other tables from database. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: sorry but Why you lock the table? I think MySQL will lock the table automatically.

Answer (score 2):

from [mysql reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html):

> A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs in a single LOCK TABLES statement. For example, in the following sequence of statements, an error occurs for the attempt to access t2 because it was not locked in the LOCK TABLES statement:
>   `mysql> LOCK TABLES t1 READ;
> mysql> SELECT COUNT() FROM t1;
> +----------+
> | COUNT() |
> +----------+
> |        3 |
> +----------+
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2;
> ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 't2' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`

Comment: while not so intuitive, locking also locks yourself out of those tables which you didnt include. so in your original lock, you need to lock all tables that you will use during the lockdown period

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably having a deadlock. Check you code for anything like:

```
LOCK TABLE link_master WRITE
/*some stuff */
SELECT * FROM invoice_numbers
/*some stuff */
UNLOCK TABLES
```

It's possible that you locked one table in one statement and the other in another statement that are both running at the same time. Just a guess though.

Check out my table locking issues at:
http://devoluk.com/mysql-myisam-table-lock-issue.html